# change the color of text in Powerpoint depending on the initial color

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint

I have 1000 powerpoint presentations where I need to change the font color from white to black.  I have found http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-powerpoint/vba-powerpoint-how-to-change-the-font-color-from/eea94b23-0892-437f-b64c-6a240f000227 but this only works if all the text in a text box is white.  There are currently highlights in many text boxes and then the color is not changed.  Anyone know how to do this, or just to inspect one character at a time?

Please.  Doing it manually would be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

In round numbers, like so, assuming you've dimmed oSh as Shape, gotten a reference to oSl as Slide.  You'd need to add tests to make sure that the shape does have a textframe and the textframe has text.  This won't touch shapes in groups or text in tables etc. but it's a start.

```
For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
    For x = 1 To oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count
        With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(x)
            ' if the charcter's color is white, make it black
            If .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next
```